Problem with high learning rate in model training
In this lecture notes Fig. 6.5, it illustrates the effect to training loss by using different learning rates: 
I don't understand why it seems a high enough non-divergent learning rate can converge to a worse local minimum compared to both the 'low learning rate' and the 'good learning rate'. Any intuition for this phenomenon (on the contrary, I recall a rule of thumb is to actually use a learning rate as high as possible without causing divergence)?

The phenomenon you're observing is related to how the learning rate affects the trajectory and stability of gradient descent as it moves through the loss landscape. Here’s some intuition to help understand why a high learning rate (even when not diverging) might converge to a worse local minimum:

When the learning rate is too high, each step taken during gradient descent is large. This can cause the optimizer to "jump" over narrow, optimal paths in the loss landscape and miss regions that would lead to better minima. Instead of carefully descending into valleys (which correspond to better minima), the optimizer can end up in broader, shallower valleys that don't reduce the loss as effectively. This is why you might see a worse local minimum despite convergence.

High learning rates introduce a kind of instability or oscillation near the minimum. Although the learning rate might be low enough to prevent complete divergence, it can still cause the optimization process to oscillate around narrow, sharp minima without properly "settling" in them.
As a result, the optimizer can settle in a region that minimizes oscillations, which might not be the best minimum but is a stable point given the high learning rate. This leads to a suboptimal convergence point compared to using a lower or “good” learning rate.

The rule of thumb to use the highest possible learning rate without causing divergence is based on the idea that higher learning rates generally speed up convergence and allow the model to escape poor local minima. However, there’s a balance: if the learning rate is too high, it can prevent the model from precisely settling into the narrow, deep minima.
"Good" learning rates hit this balance by being high enough to accelerate convergence and escape bad minima but low enough to allow the optimizer to "fine-tune" its position in the loss landscape and settle into an optimal point.


